# R: changing the size of some (but not all) plotted data points according to their weighting

Tags: r, plot

I have generated a plot in R in which the size of each data point corresponds to its individual weighting, for instance like this:

```
x <- runif(10, 2, 200) 
y <- runif(10, 5.0, 7.5)
weighting <- c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 10, 15, 15, 25, 25)
```

I have adjusted the size of the plotted data ponts with `cex`:

`plot(x, y, cex = weighting)`

Since some data points in the plot are very large because of their high weighting factors, I have reduced the size of all points by `plot(x, y, cex = weighting/5)` which would give a plot like:
[image: Example 1]

Unfortunately, data points with a small weighting are tiny now. I'm sure there is a possibility to limit the sizing only to those points which have a high weighting factor and to plot the others (*i.e. weighting = 1*) at normal size. I don't know how to do that, can anybody help?

Comment: whynot with an ifelse ? plot(x, y, cex = ifelse(weighting>1, weighting/5, weighting))

Comment: Thank you, that works! Amazingly I didn't knew the ifelse-command, yet , but it seems very useful for many purposes...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may also have a look at `scale_size_area` in `ggplot`

```
# you need to keep your data in a data.frame
df <- data.frame(x = x, y = y, weighting = weighting)
ggplot(data = df, aes(x = x, y = y, size = weighting)) +
  geom_point() +
  scale_size_area()
```

**Update, on `cex` and scaling of point size**
Because the topic of the question is `cex`, I take the opportunity to cite [a post by @Bert Gunter](https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-help/2011-January/265475.html) on R-help:

"Here's the problem: in order to accurately
represent the value, the "point" = circle *area* must be proportional
to the value. That is, the eye "sees" the areas, not the radii, as the
point "size." A delightful reference on this is Howard Wainer's 1982
or so (can't remember exactly) article in THE AMERICAN STATISTICIAN,
"How to Graph Data Badly" (or maybe "Plot" Data).

Anyway, using cex, I have no idea whether a point drawn with cex =
1.23 is 1.23 times the area or radius -- or neither -- of a point
drawn with cex =1. Indeed, it might vary depending on the
implementation/OS/graphics fonts.  So it seems better to me to "draw"
the point with symbols(), where you can have complete control over the
size.

Obviously, let me know if I'm wrong about this." End quotation.

In the same thread @Gabor Grothendieck points to [this nice article](http://flowingdata.com/2010/11/23/how-to-make-bubble-charts/), where the `base` function `symbols` is used. One example where "[c]ircles [are] incorrectly sized by radius instead of area. Large values appear much bigger", and one where "Circles [are] correctly sized by area", and also where the `inches` argument is used to set size the largest bubble. I think this might be a `base` equivalent to `scale_size_area()` in `ggplot`.

Comment: user2790580, I have updated my answer with a small note on `cex` and size of points.

Comment: @user2790580, great that you found my answer helpful!

Answer (score 1):

How about plotting with `log` of `weighting` for size?

`plot(x, y, cex = log10(weighting))`

Answer (score 0):

The function `pmax` might help:

```
minCex <- 1
plot(x, y, cex = pmax(minCex, weighting / 5))
```